# Logomatic v2 serial SD Datalogger issues

Tags: datalogger, usb, microsd

Hi i bought this data logger a few weeks ago, http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/products/Logomatic-v2-Serial-SD-Datalogger.html

I've been having some trouble with it. I read the data sheet and I've powered it up (using a 2Gb Sandisk micro sd card formatted to FAT16 512 allocation size and powered by 2 AA batteries). The data sheet says that on initial startup the leds should blink rapidly and then stop. What I'm having happen is that the usb light will go on and after about 30 seconds the stat1 and stat0 will also light up and they will all stay on. When I turn the unit off and then connect it to the usb, my computer (Windows 7 64bit, also tried 32bit) says that the device has malfunctioned and it cannot install the drivers. I then tried uninstalling the SD card and connecting it to my computer but it shows that the SD card is empty and there are no log files contained on it.

I really need to get this working in the next week for my uni major project so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks heaps,

Answer (score 4):

This definitely sounds like a USB issue with the computer.  The device is obviously not recognized and thus its startup can't continue past a certain point.  I'm guessing that the LEDs blinking rapidly is initial USB activity and it sounds like that isn't happening correctly.

First, have you tried it on several computers?  Do you have any non-windows computers to try it on?

It looks like the board might incorporate several USB devices - USB mass storage being one.  If the SD card is not formatted correctly for the board then that might stop the startup of the mass storage device.  Try reformatting it again and see what happens.  I doubt it will work but you never know.

Try a different (smaller if you have it) SD card and see what happens.

If you have the programming adapter mentioned in the datasheet, attempt to re-flash the firmware or even try the alternate firmware provided.

Comment: I tried it on a windows xp computer and it does connect as a mass storage device and shows that the sd card is empty. I've formatted the sd card about 4 times and tried different allocation sizes but i havent gotten anywhere.

I'll try a smaller sd card and see how it goes.

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 2):

You said TWO AA batteries -- try THREE. It needs 3.6 - 7.5v power.

Comment: I got one of these boards today, I plugged in a 5V wall wart and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The usuall problem is the the SD card needs to be fat16, and less than 2G.  Try reformating the card